# serializeArray not working for the fields generated from the ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax

```js
$(document).on("click","#addressModal",function(){
            var addressId=$(this).attr("caddressId");

            $.ajax({
                url: "ajax/customerDetails_ajax.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: "get=getAddressDetails&addressId="+addressId,

                success: function(result){
                    $("#getAddress").html(result)
                },
                error: function(result){
                    alert("Error")
                }
            })

        })

$(document).on("click","#updateCustomerAddressDetails",function(){

            console.log($("#serviceLocation").val())

            var data = $("#addressEditForm").serializeArray()
            console.log(data)
            $.ajax({
                url: "ajax/customerDetails_ajax.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: data,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(result){
                    //console.log(result)
                    if(result.status == "success"){
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
                },
                error: function(result){
                    alert("Error")
                }
            })
        });
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="editAddress">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Address</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form id="addressEditForm" method="post">
                                <div id="getAddress">
                                    <!-- address details will be displayed here via ajax response -->
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="updateCustomerAddressDetails" name="updateCustomerAddressDetails">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
                </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
            </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

I am trying to serialize the data fetched from the ajax response and sending it to another ajax response. But, since the data is being fetched from the ajax, the data isn't being serialized. It generates a blank array.

Comment: Is there any chance to see result of first ajax request? Also did you try to use append() instead of html() ?

Comment: here it is. http://prntscr.com/74pkjl

Comment: So, here i got the solution and issue.

Answer (score 0):

If I haven't included the form in the ajax response, it doesn't cache the values for serialization.

Now, I'm sending the encapsulated  output in the form inside ajax response.